# Undo Log error: No more space left over in system tablespace for allocating UNDO log pages

Tags: sql, linux, database

I am importing a csv file into a table in a mysql database using *load data infile* command. The csv file is pretty big (around 10 Gig). In the middle of the import, I get the following error:

**Undo Log error: No more space left over in system tablespace for allocating UNDO log pages. Please add new data file to the tablespace or check if filesystem is full or enable auto-extension for the tablespace**

What is this error for?

Comment: What's your DBMS?

Comment: It is MYSQL database

Answer (score 3):

The MySQL system comes with a way to rollback changes using this "UNDO log file". It's also used for coherency. With large datasets, that log file may grow *too fast* and be filled up. Then you get that error. The idea is to be able to undo the last command. This is similar to going in a paint system, for example, making changes to an image and then clicking <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>. That's what the UNDO log file is there for.

To avoid having the table running, you can mark it as inactive:

```
ALTER UNDO TABLESPACE tablespace_name SET INACTIVE;
```

You can also delete the table altogether (not recommended) or allow for auto-truncation, which may be slow. The auto-truncate makes sure to remove data *as required*.

For more info you can [see here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-undo-tablespaces.html).

Comment: @mcmillab, unfortunately, the OP never commented. However, checking my answer today, I can see that it was a tad bit too short. I've made two updates: I've added a command that is likely to help you in the process and the link goes to version 8.0 which includes documentation about these solutions.