# MySQL - How to delete the UNDO log with the CLI on Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I tried to update a few million rows in my MySQL database, but I couldn't because of the UNDO log pages. I got this message:

> Undo Log error: No more space left over in system tablespace for
> allocating UNDO log pages. Please add new data file to the tablespace
> or check if filesystem is full or enable auto-extension for the
> tablespace

The problem is that now I am stuck, because I have no more space on my server.

[image]

I first tried to clear the pages of the UNDO journal, as explained [there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51667151/939116):

```
ALTER UNDO TABLESPACE tablespace_name SET INACTIVE;
```

But it didn't work.

After searching for a solution to remove the UNDO log without success, I decided to restart my server. But now it's even worse because I can't start MySQL anymore, it works the same way:

> sudo: unable to resolve host *********: Resource temporarily
> unavailable [....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob
> for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error
> code. See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for
> details.  failed!

How can I fix this? I can not make room on my server because it is completely filled with my MySQL database. Anyway, I can't connect to it anymore.

Is there any way to delete the UNDO log with the CLI?